# How do I fix a counting algorithm that deletes on a random value?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a counting channel, but my algorithm isn't working: it works until I reach the number 9. When I do get to that number, it starts deleting my message. I'm thinking that this is the root of all my problems: `if int(message.content[0]) != self.cum_num + 1`. I know that `self.cum_num + 1` doesn't change the value of `self.cum_num`, but I do want to be able to compare the incremented by 1 version of this variable to the number the user sends into the counting channel.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.channel.id == self.count_channel:
            try:
                if int(message.content[0]) != self.cum_num + 1:
                    await message.delete()
                else:
                    self.cum_num += 1
            except ValueError:
                await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `int(message.content[0]) != self.cum_num + 1`. If you type in 10 it will grab the first letter `1` and not `10` so it will compare `1 != 10`.
Use this to be able to go above 9:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.channel.id == self.count_channel:
            try:
                if int(message.content) != self.cum_num + 1:
                    await message.delete()
                else:
                    self.cum_num += 1
            except ValueError:
                await message.delete()
```